# print the first link in the document

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to print the first link in the page with JavaScript. But when I use the following code, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <a id="mylink" href="http://google.com">Google</a><br />
        <script>            
            a=$('mylink').href;
            document.write(document.links[0]);                  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I commented out the code "`a=$('mylink').href`", it suddenly worked, why? How come the varable `a` has any influence on the next statement?

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few possibilities:

1. The object `$` is not defined and caused a JavaScript error preventing your 2nd statement to execute
2. The `$` object does not know what to do with the string passed in and errors
3. The returned value from `$` does not have a value (ie - it returns `undefined`) which wont have a property `href`, causing a JavaScript error

Comment: Oh, I was more concerned about the variable a rather than the $ sign. $ is the cause of this problem. Thank you Slace!

Answer (score 1):

the code is not working because in your example the $ object does not exist and will cause an error. It seems that you were trying to use a JavaScript framework like jQuery ($ object) but you forgot to include it.

Try to add the following script-Tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to use jQuery, you should also access attributes via the .attr("attrname") function. E.g.

```
var a = $('#mylink').attr('href');
```

Again if you wanted to use jQuery, you have to alter the selector from "mylink" to "#mylink" to specify that you were searching for the element with the id "mylink".

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to do, but couldn't you just write the whole link in js? Ex:

```
<script>
<!--
document.write('<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>');
-->
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</noscript>
```

The comment tag in the script is ignored and is only there so browsers that don't support javacript won't print it in the document. The `<noscript>` is so browsers that don't support javascript have alternate content.

Comment: I am trying out examples from a JavaScript Textbook and came across this example. But your approach is definitely practical.

Comment: There's no point in wrapping your JavaScript in comments unless you're supporting Netscape 2 or IE < 3

Comment: @Slace—HTML comment delimiters aren't neede for those browsers either. In fact, they were never needed for standards compliant browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `a=$('mylink').href` fails to execute and stop executing of following code. The code `document.write(document.links[0])` is correct. When you call it without previous wrong line, it just works.

I think in the first line you're trying to use jQuery library. If you want to do it, you need to include jQuery library using `<script>` tag, then use the following code:

```
document.write($('a:first').attr("href"));
```

Comment: That selects the first A element, not the first link. They might be the same thing, but the first A might be an anchor (target).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the jQuery stuff, you don't need it. As you've already discovered, there is a [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection so if you want to print the herf value of the first link in the document:

```
document.write(document.links[0].href)
```

and you're done.